# Dead simple flowcharting tool

Tags: flowchart, diagramming

I'm making quick and dirty flows of my software for non-technical users. I'd like something that can output to PNG or other graphic format and that they could easily get into and use to make updates and modifications. Something light...

Comment: generate flowcharts programatically?

Comment: Like Google Drawings ... :)http://www.google.com/google-d-s/drawings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

visio works well..

Comment: I've been using that but wanted something my users could also use. However, at this point it's just as easy for me to create them in Visio and have them just draw on the printouts.

Answer (score 5):

I like [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html). It has a simple, yet powerful, interface with lots of options. Put in the boxes, label them, and connect them with arrows. Then use a hierarchical, incremental, layout to arrange them. It's Java, and can be tried out online.

Answer (score 5):

http://code2flow.com - dead simple (pseudo-code to flowchart), share links, PDF & PNG & SVG support, Atlassian plugins and free online version. Click on below sample to open editor. Note that I am involved in this solution.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We product [draw.io](https://www.draw.io), works natively in any browser, no login/registration, free to save/load/export, not Flash based.

Answer (score 1):

Try LucidChart (http://www.lucidchart.com).  By far the easiest and best looking flow charts I've ever made.  Sounds like you could really use its collaboration feature as well (beats sending files back and forth via email)